# Why does this type of function prototyping throwing an error?

Tags: c++

This is my code

```
#include<iostream>
//#include<cmath>
double sqrt(double);

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << sqrt(16) << endl;
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

I am only exploring into c++ and supposedly[C++ Primer, Lippman] this form of function prototyping should be working.
My code works if I replace `double sqrt(double);`
with the commented line `#include<cmath>`

But why does the other method throw this error:

```
    $ g++ so_c++1_FntnPrototype.cpp -lm
    /tmp/cc45Ec4F.o: In function `main':
    so_c++1_FntnPrototype.cpp:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `sqrt(double)'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Have you considered pasting "undefined reference to sqrt" into a web-based search engine?

Comment: `std::sqrt` and `sqrt` are different names.

Comment: @BoBTFish I don't think that matters here.

Comment: Yes, @juanchopanza, most answers suggest adding -lm to the command but that doesn't apply here

Comment: You just _define_ a NEW function named `sqrt` that takes a double and returns a double, but the compiler knows nothing about how it is implemented. If you use `#include<cmath>`, then compiler knows you are talking about THAT `sqrt` function which is included in one of the runtime libraries.

Comment: Thanks @kennyzx, I understand your explanation. It makes sense.
Just that, the book I am reading suggested this should work as the compiler would interpret it implicitly.

Comment: check @kennyzx comment, it pretty clear and is the answer to your question

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone

Comment: @Sharan, this is what every body learns on day 1 ;) And don't get frustrated by the downvotes. It is not personal.

Comment: @kennyzx that's not entirely true, compiler could know that `sqrt` refers to **that** `sqrt`, provided you specified it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that functions in math library (`-lm`) have C linkage. If you modify `sqrt` prototype to indicate that it should have C linkage, your program links fine:

```
#include<iostream>

extern "C" double sqrt(double);

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << sqrt(16) << endl;
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

(BTW. that's why header files are used - so you don't have to remember about such details)

Answer (score 1):

Names of library functions are reserved. C++14 [extern.names]/3:

> Each name from the Standard C library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a name with `extern "C"` linkage, both in namespace `std` and in the global namespace.
>
> Each function signature from the Standard C library declared with external linkage is reserved to the
>   implementation for use as a function signature with both extern "C" and extern "C++" linkage, or as a name of namespace scope in the global namespace.

Being reserved to the implementation means that it's undefined behaviour if you try to declare the name:

> If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by this Clause, its behavior is undefined.

[Undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) means that anything can happen;  in this case that includes the code failing to compile.

Comment: I don't know how it actually *answers* question.

Comment: @el.pescado undefined behaviour means that anything can happen (including a compilation error in this case)

Comment: OK, after reading it like 4 times it starts to make sense, but I still think it's pretty hard to understand for someone starting to learn C++.